# Javascript TextBoxInput from function change value

Tags: javascript, function, textbox, parameter-passing

I have a problem.
 This fuction recive a textboxInput, (is called by two textbox), and I want to replace the user text with my restrictions.
but I dont know how to replace the textbox to the textBoxInput

```
    function validarRutPromise(textBoxInput) {
        var textBox = textBoxInput.value; // the string in the textBoxInput
        alert(textBox); 
        textBox = textBox.toUpperCase();
        textBox = textBox.replace(".", "");
        textBox = textBox.replace(".", "");
        textBox = textBox.replace("-", "");
        textBoxInput.value(textBox); --- This line doesnt work!
```

Im reading, but document.getElementById, or document.getElementByName doesnt match because, my textBoxInput have a dinamical name

and Y call the function by:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` isn't a function, it's a property. Just assign it like you would any variable:

```
textBoxInput.value = textBox;
```

**Aside:**

You can simplify your `replace()` calls with RegEx:

```
textBox = textBox.replace(/[-\.]+/, "");
```